# Convert the indices to slices or integers :" TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, typeerror

I have created lists from my data frame (df1)and I am trying to subtract the values(high tide and low tide) and plot them but keep getting stuck with the maximums. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Intel\Solinst-cleaned up\yellow.csv', skiprows = 13, encoding= 'unicode_escape', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])

# Normal condition (From Jan 20th to Feb 11th)
start = 50     # First row to consider
stop = 3200     # Last row to consider
interval = 75  # The desired chunk size
x=df1['Date_Time'][50:125]

y1=[]
for i in range(start, stop, interval):
    y1.append(df1["Mlevel"][i:(i + interval)])
    
#y1 = y1.reset_index(drop=True)

hightide=[]   
for i in range(start, stop, interval):
    hightide=max(y1[1].loc[y1['Mlevel'][i:(i + interval)]])
```

And I get :

```
  File "C:/Users/mr179/Desktop/Research/PhD/codes/test.py", line 42, in <module>
    hightide=max(y1[1].loc[y1['Mlevel'][i:(i + interval)]])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

y1 looks like this:

[image: screenshot of text data]

Comment: When asking a code related question, please **always** add a tag for the language being used. It helps get the question to the people who can answer it, and it helps when users are searching for answers related to that language. Also, when asking about an error, you should **always** include the exact, complete error message you're getting in the question body, not just quote part of the error. You should [edit] to add that error message.

Comment: You change `y1=len(y1)` to `y1len=len(y1)`.  You have overwritten your carefully constructed array with a single integer.  Even then, it's not going to work, because that final loop thinks it is a dictionary or a dataframe.  It's just a list of rows.  And why is that final thing a loop at all?  You don't use `i` inside it.

Comment: `y1=len(y1)` converts `y1` into being an integer, one that you subsequently try to treat as if it was a list (or similar data structure). What do you think `y1=len(y1)` does? I don't see any motivation for that line.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error?

Comment: Thank you guys, I added the full error. After I edited my code and removed len(y1), now I get "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" . The data in my list are float type though.

Comment: @Mo-Raz Please add the full error message including traceback. From skimming the code, it looks like the problem is at `y1['Mlevel']`. `y1` is a list, so what are you expecting to happen there? Is it supposed to be `df1`?

Comment: @wjandrea I added the traceback and the problem is on the last line (hightide=max(y1[1].loc[y1['Mlevel'][i:(i + interval)]]))

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you, I removed that line. I want to get the maximums in each loop and make a list of those maximums to be plotted or compared later. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Right, but what are you expecting to happen? `y1` is a list, which of course doesn't support indexing by str.

Comment: Do you just want to know the maximum value of `Mlevel` in each interval?  Pandas can do that directly:  `df["Mlevel"][i:i+interval].max()`  Or maybe `df.loc[i:i+interval]["Mlevel"].max()`.